# Scala/Clojure compile dependency

Tags: scala, clojure, compilation, sbt

We use sbt-clojure in Scala project (https://github.com/Geal/sbt-clojure).

In one subproject there are Scala-code, which are imported in Clojure code.
In this case, Clojure doesn't see Scala-code (by "sbt compile", by default Clojure compiles earlier than Scala).

How can sbt compile Scala-code before Clojure-code?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and simply forked and modified the plugin: https://github.com/tomaszym/sbt-clojure Might be just enough also for you, if you don't mind firing *clojurec* instead of *compile*.

Answer (score -2):

I would use Maven that supports both Scala and Clojure.

Maven has clojure-maven-plugin for Cloture and the maven-scala-plugin for Scala. You can arrange order of compilation of the both language source code.